# Copying Files with Spaces

Tags: java, apache, file, file-io, copy

I'm trying to copy one file to another directory, but the way I am copying the file is not working when the source path has a directory with spaces in it, e.g.

```
/Volumes/public/Music/Directory With Spaces/01.mp3
```

I am using: `http://commons.apache.org/io/`

I can't find a way around this, any ideas?

Edit: The problem should probably be putting paths with spaces into a java.io.File object.

Comment: Weird. What happens when you do `new File("/Volumes/public/Music/").listFiles()`? Is `Directory With Spaces` included?

Comment: (And if it's included, does it work?)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 1.1, then you should be able to use '%20' to refer to a space.

Source: http://commons.apache.org/io/upgradeto1_1.html

Answer (score 0):

If you create a `java.io.File` object with the directory you stated, does it find it?  Does it find the file (i.e. `file.exists()` returns `true`)?  My thought is that you need to encode it in a `File` object, or a `URI`/`URL` object.  However, I am not intimately familiar with the Apache IO libraries, as I tend to use the standard ones in the Java releases.

If the path works with the standard Java IO libraries, then that would point to some different handling with the Apache IO libraries.  If it doesn't, I would attempt to get it working with those first, and then use a `File` object to get it working fully.

Comment: Doing file.exists() throws false. Using both %20 or escaped spaces fails for the path for java.io.File.

Comment: Take a look at David Mole's comments - it sounds like there is something that is different from what you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with escaped spaces:
`/Volumes/public/Music/Directory\ With\ Spaces/01.mp3`

Comment: Doesn't like that either. That was my first idea, but nothing different.