# copy files in java with path containing whitespace

Tags: java, file, io, copy, whitespace

How to copy files in java where file name or its path has white spaces?
I've used this method:

```
import static java.nio.file.*;

Files.copy(source, target, REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

source & target paths have been set using Paths.get() method.
But it throws `NoSuchFileException` for paths with white spaces. The target system is Ubuntu.
This question [Copying Files with Spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359625/copying-files-with-spaces) has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following with a problem (spaces in directory and filenames)

```
Path source = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\plawrey\\Google Drive\\IFAQ - Chronicle.gdoc");
Path target = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\plawrey\\Google Drive\\IFAQ - Chronicle2.gdoc");
Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Perhaps the problem is that your target directory doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that target system is Ubuntu. I've edited it now. Code does not work on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you try doing the same thing on the command line with cp using quotes for the filenames?  I have never seen a problem with spaces on any Linux.

Comment: Yes, the same string works fine on terminal.I tried adding double quotes using escape sequences as well but without success.

Comment: @RuturajPatil can you give us the actual string?

Comment: Sorry again; I solved the problem; It was actually due to file permissions issue on a mounted drive;